# Core Data (iPhone)- Limiting the fetch results across a relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, relationship, fetch

I have recently been looking at Core Data for the iPhone and I have one query which I have not been able to find an answer to in the literature.

Lets imagine that I have a **User** model object with a to-many relationship with a **Purchase** object. A **User** may have thousands of purchases.

All of the information I have seen thus far seems to suggest that a fetch operation carried out across that relationship would return an NSSet with all of the **Purchase** objects associated with a particular **User**.

Clearly I would prefer if there was some way to limit the number of **Purchase** objects fetched by:

1) imposing some sort of criteria (e.g. only purchases over £1000 etc.); or

2) only fetching in batches if the above is not possible.

Is the above possible? I am just concerned that with the limited memory of the iPhone that I risk overloading it with thousands of unnecessarily fetched objects.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that when you fetch User objects, the relationship to its Purchase objects will be a fault that will only be loaded if accessed.
Instead, you could fetch Purchase objects with a predicate that specifies the User(s) and check(s) on any other criteria.

That said, I would definitely test realistic use cases (on devices) before spending too much time on performance issues. The efficiency of the iPhone and Core Data may surprise you.

Comment: Not sure if I should be opening a new question based on your answer so I'll ask here first: 1) Once the Purchase fault is fired, does that mean every single Purchase object for that User gets loaded too? 2) If I use a predicate instead, do I not rely on the User -->> Purchase relationship at all, and instead use some other field to link a User to its Purchases and a completely different fetch request?

Comment: Not sure. Probably worth opening a new question if you haven't already or reviewing the Core Data Programming Guide (linked by Barry Wark's answer).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use a fetched property
2. Use `NSFetchedResultsController`

The answer to these and the questions you will have next are answered in the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) for the iPhone.